# Needleman Wunsch Algorithm (perl)

Tags: algorithm, perl, matrix

So my problem is trying to implement the Needleman Wunsch algorithim and the gapscores for the vertical and horizontal run out of memory and do not implement correctly. It is probably a simple loop miscalculation in memory but for the life of me I am unable to see it. Here is the code:

```
$seq1 = "ACTTCAATCGGT";
$seq2 = "ACTGGTCAATCGGT";
$len1 = length($seq1);
$len2 = length($seq2);
```

The sequence above.

```
@matrix = ();
my $gapscore = -1;

my $matchscore = 1;
my $mismatchscore = 0;
$matrix[0][0] = 0;

# initialize 1st row and 1st column of matrix decreasing by $gapscore
for ($i = 1; $i < $len1; $i++) {
    $matrix[$i][0] = $gapscore;
    $gapscore--;
}

$gapscore = -1; 

for ($j = 1; $j < $len2; $j++) {
     $matrix[0][$j] = $gapscore;         
     $gapscore--;

}

$gapscore = -1;
```

So the code above correctly implements the matrix spots with 0...n and 0...n going horizontally and vertically. The next code attempts to implement the matrix by filling in the rest of the values in the matrix.

```
for($x = 1; $x < $len2; $x++) { # going through sequence1
   for($y = 1; $y < $len1; $y++) { # going through sequence2

        my ($diagonal, $horizontal, $vertical); 

        my $Firstletter = substr($seq1,$x-1,1);
        my $Secondletter = substr($seq2,$y-1,1); 


        # gap scores:
        $vertical = $matrix[$x-1][$y] + $gapscore;
        $horizontal = $matrix[$x][$y-1] + $gapscore;

        # matching scores on diagonal:
        if($Firstletter eq $Secondletter) {
             $diagonal = $matrix[$x-1][$y-1] + $matchscore;
        }
        else {
             $diagonal = $matrix[$x-1][$y-1] + $mismatchscore;
        } 
    }
}
```

The vertical and horizontal variables are causing memory issues. I'm not sure why. If anyone could provide some insight I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Memory issues as in what? Index out of range, out of memory, taking too long - all could be considered "memory issues"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see why you're running out of memory, but you have some off-by-one errors. The matrix has one more columns than there are bases in sequence 1, and one more rows than there are bases in sequence 2. That means your indices should run from 0 to `$len1` and 0 to `$len2`, but you are stopping one short.

This should help you. It builds the array correctly, but I haven't written the next step which is to track optimum paths through the diagonal.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util 'max';

STDOUT->autoflush;

my ($seq1, $seq2) = qw/ ACTTCAATCGGT ACTGGTCAATCGGT /;
my ($len1, $len2) = map length, $seq1, $seq2;
my @seq1 = $seq1 =~ /./g;
my @seq2 = $seq2 =~ /./g;

my @matrix;
$matrix[$_][0] = -$_ for 0 .. $len2;
$matrix[0][$_] = -$_ for 0 .. $len1;

for my $x ( 1 .. $len2 ) {     # Rows (bases of sequence 2)
    for my $y ( 1 .. $len1 ) { # Columns (bases of sequence 1)

        my $match = $seq1[$y-1] eq $seq2[$x-1];

        my @scores = (
          $matrix[$x-1][$y] - 1,  # Up
          $matrix[$x][$y-1] - 1,  # Left
          $match ? $matrix[$x-1][$y-1] + 1 : $matrix[$x-1][$y-1] - 1, # Diagonal
        );

        $matrix[$x][$y] = max @scores;
    }        
}

for my $i ( 0 .. $len2 ) {
    my $row = $matrix[$i];
    print join(' ', map { sprintf '%3d', $_ } @$row), "\n";
}
```

**output**

```
  0  -1  -2  -3  -4  -5  -6  -7  -8  -9 -10 -11 -12
 -1   1   0  -1  -2  -3  -4  -5  -6  -7  -8  -9 -10
 -2   0   2   1   0  -1  -2  -3  -4  -5  -6  -7  -8
 -3  -1   1   3   2   1   0  -1  -2  -3  -4  -5  -6
 -4  -2   0   2   2   1   0  -1  -2  -3  -2  -3  -4
 -5  -3  -1   1   1   1   0  -1  -2  -3  -2  -1  -2
 -6  -4  -2   0   2   1   0  -1   0  -1  -2  -2   0
 -7  -5  -3  -1   1   3   2   1   0   1   0  -1  -1
 -8  -6  -4  -2   0   2   4   3   2   1   0  -1  -2
 -9  -7  -5  -3  -1   1   3   5   4   3   2   1   0
-10  -8  -6  -4  -2   0   2   4   6   5   4   3   2
-11  -9  -7  -5  -3  -1   1   3   5   7   6   5   4
-12 -10  -8  -6  -4  -2   0   2   4   6   8   7   6
-13 -11  -9  -7  -5  -3  -1   1   3   5   7   9   8
-14 -12 -10  -8  -6  -4  -2   0   2   4   6   8  10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for($x = 1; $x < $len2; $x++) { # going through sequence1
   for($y = 1; $y < $len1; $y++) { # going through sequence2
```

Wrong, the first loop, as written, goes through `sequence2` and the second through `sequence1`.

So it looks like you've inverted your indexes. This can lead to index out of range errors and also slower execution time in some cases.

Possible fix: swap `len2` and `len1` in the code above.